# Ошибка php библиотеки

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, yii, dll

Все доброго дня!
Поставил себе последний линукс минт (та же убунту 16.04), накатил ЛАМП. Создал хост, установил туда YII. Все вроде прошло как по маслу. Но при открытии сайта выдает ошибку "PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_xmlrpc.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/php_xmlrpc.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory", то есть как я понял, не может найти dll библиотеку, что собственно меня и поставило в тупик. Откуда в лине dll-ки. 
Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону смотреть, куда копать. Я в полном замешательстве.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: КО говорит, что копать надо в сторону установки библиотеки php-xmlrpc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте выполнить следующую команду:

```
sudo apt install php5-xmlrpc
```

После чего перезапустите Apache и проверьте.

Но, вообще, что-то очень странное у Вас творится - почему он пытается обратиться к DLL, а не в линуксовой библиотеке?

Возможно, Вы используете какую-то сборку, "заточенную" под Windows - проверьте :)

Comment: "*почему он пытается обратиться к DLL*" обращается он к сошке, просто диагностика такая, тянется с древних версий ещё.

Comment: @PinkTux, спасибо за разъяснение. Всё встало на свои места! :)

Comment: @PinkTux, Спасибо) Тоже помогли с разъяснениями.